# Expectation values of commutator and anti-commutator (momentum and position)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, commutator, anticommutator

What are the expectation values of commutator and anti-commutator for momentum and position operators?
In the case of commutator:
$$\langle[x,p]\rangle=\langle i\hbar\rangle=~?$$
In the case of anti-commutator:
$$\langle   \{x,p\}\rangle=~?$$

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30248/what-is-expectation-values-of-this-anti-commutator-langle-delta-hat-x-de).

Comment: If you ask for the expectation value you must mention in which state you want to know it, i.d. $<\psi|[x,p]|\psi>$. In any state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$i\hbar$ is simply a number, or if you must regard it as an operator, a multiple of the identity. So $\langle i\hbar \rangle=i\hbar$, and so is $\langle -i\hbar \rangle$.

By the way, anticommutator of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ is not $[\hat{p},\hat{x}]$, but $\{\hat{x},\hat{p}\}=\hat{x}\hat{p}+\hat{p}\hat{x}$.

Comment: you means that $\langle -i\hbar\rangle=i\hbar$!?

Comment: $\langle -i\hbar\rangle= -i\hbar$. The expectation of any constant is just that constant.

Answer (score 1):

Expectation values of constants or numbers are just those constants or numbers.

The expectation value of the anti commutator of $\hat x$ and $\hat p$, that is, $\langle\{\hat x,\ \hat p\}\rangle$,  **for the Harmonic Oscillator, or coherent states of the Harmonic Oscillator**, is equal to $0$. $$\langle n|\{\hat x,\ \hat p\}|n \rangle = \langle\hat x \hat p + \hat p \hat x\rangle = \langle \hat x \hat p\rangle + \langle\hat p \hat x\rangle = \langle\frac{i\hbar}2\rangle + \langle\frac{-i\hbar}2\rangle = \frac{i\hbar}2 - \frac{i\hbar}2 = 0$$

Comment: Why is $\langle\hat x\hat p\rangle=\frac{i\hbar}{2}$?

Comment: @JahanClaes It's not. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: OK, I've re-added the remark about the SHO.

Comment: JahanClaes, @Chris, can you please take a look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155089/expected-value-of-xp-in-harmonic-oscillator

Comment: @Chris, I've re-added the specific remark about the Harmonic Oscillator. You are right that it's not true in general, and I was wrong when I removed that remark. Thanks for pointing it out. The answer is now correct.

Comment: @MauroLacy Is it true for coherent states? I believe it is only for stationary states. Which makes it pretty much useless as a relation. It certainly is misleading to write $\langle\{\hat x,\ \hat p\}\rangle = \langle\hat x \hat p + \hat p \hat x\rangle = \langle \hat x \hat p\rangle + \langle\hat p \hat x\rangle = \langle\frac{i\hbar}2\rangle + \langle\frac{-i\hbar}2\rangle = \frac{i\hbar}2 - \frac{i\hbar}2 = 0$: it should at least have something like $\langle n|\{\hat x,\ \hat p\} |n\rangle$ to show it is only for stationary states.

Comment: It's true for coherent states too, yes.

Comment: @MauroLacy Regardless, that should be signified more clearly.

Comment: Chris is, ***of course***  [right](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/30314/66086).  In the phase space QM picture, this is self-evident; but, even in Hilbert space, displaced states, etc..., the bread-and-butter of squeezing, violate vanishing of the expectation of the anticommutator. Just because it *can* be made to hold for *some* states, exceptionally,  does not permit using it as an example of an abstract relationship and conveying unsound impressions.