# Expected value of $xp$ in harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I wanna find out the expected value of the $xp$ operator for the $n$-th excited state of the harmonic oscillator, i.e. calculate the value $\langle n|xp|n \rangle$. I express the position and momentum operators in terms of the ladder operators:

$$x = \frac{x_0}{\sqrt{2}} \left( a+a^{\dagger}\right)$$
$$p = \frac{p_0}{i\sqrt{2}} \left( a-a^{\dagger}\right)$$

Where $x_0,p_0$ are the scales, $x_0p_0 = \hbar$. Since $$\langle n|a^m|n \rangle =0$$

For every $m$, and likewise for $a^\dagger$. So the only term that doesn't yield a zero expectation value after multiplying will be the commutator term, yielding $-1$. Which still leaves me with an imaginary answer of $\frac{i \hbar}{2}$. Where's the mistake?

Comment: Can you perhaps explain why exactly you think there's something wrong?

Comment: I think there's something wrong because isn't $xp$ an observable quantity? So why does it have imaginary expectation?

Comment: @DepeHb Did you check whether $xp$ could be an observable quantity? Do you know how to check?

Comment: Is it really a mistake? Let me see using QM. For calculating $-i \hbar \int dx \ x \ \psi^* \frac {∂ \psi}{∂x}$, we can integrate by parts and obtain $i \hbar \int dx \frac {∂ (x\psi ^*)}{∂x}\psi$ which is further equal to  $i \hbar \int dx \ \psi ^* \psi$ + $i \hbar \int dx \ x \frac {∂\psi ^*}{∂x}\psi$ So, look what I get: $Re[-i \hbar \int dx \ x \ \psi^* \frac {∂ \psi}{∂x}] = \frac {1}{2} i \hbar \int dx \ \psi ^* \psi$ $,

Comment: The heart of the question (v2) seems spurred by a false expectation that _the product of two self-adjoint operators is again self-adjoint._ This is not necessarily true.

Comment: *Shhhh!!!* @Qmechanic. Don't spoil the learning process! ;)

Comment: I guess something is an observable iff its operator is self-adjoint. Is this right: $(xp)^\dagger = p^\dagger x^\dagger = px \neq xp$ ?

Comment: @DepeHb You've got the idea! However, the iff statement isn't quite true: not every Hermitian operator is needfully an observable, but observables are certainly Hermitian.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Also, take care when interchanging 'hermitian' and 'self-adjoint'.

Comment: @Danu You're right.

Comment: @Danu: I think the realization and embarrassment will spare the OP from making the mistake again, whether it was revealed to him/her or not :)

Comment: @DepeHb The other comments here practically answer your question. I simply offer a quick verification of your answer. You have calculated $\langle xp \rangle = \frac{ i \hbar }{2} $. Taking a complex conjugate, we find $\langle px \rangle = - \frac{i \hbar }{2}$. Subtracting the two, we get $\langle (xp-px) \rangle = i \hbar$ which is consistent with $[x,p] = i \hbar$. This kind of simple checks should give you extra confidence in your answer next time. **Would this work if your answer was real, as you originally thought?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already worked out, $(xp)^\dagger = p^\dagger x^\dagger = px \neq xp$, so that  the product of two self-adjoint operators is not needfully self-adjoint, and indeed from this equation we see that the product is self adjoint if and only if $p$ and $x$ commute.

To complete your thinking, how indeed do we calculate the product of the two measurements if we impart measurement $p$ first, then $x$? As you have already worked out for yourself, it can't be $\langle n|xp|n \rangle$.

Suppose our beginning quantum state is $\psi$ and impart $p$, getting measurement $\mu(p,\,\alpha)$ if the measurement forces our state into eigenvector $\psi_\alpha$, with probability $|\langle \psi_\alpha|\psi \rangle|^2$. Then, we impart $x$, and the mean value of this measurement is $\langle\psi_\alpha |x|\psi_\alpha\rangle$.

So the mean value of the product of the two measurements is:

$$\langle\psi|\left(\sum\limits_\alpha \langle\psi_\alpha |x|\psi_\alpha\rangle\,\mu(p,\,\alpha)\,|\psi_\alpha\rangle\langle\psi_\alpha|\right)|\psi\rangle$$

which we can write $\langle\psi|P_x|\psi\rangle$ where $P_x$ is the self adjoint observable:

$$P_x=\sum\limits_\alpha \langle\psi_\alpha |x|\psi_\alpha\rangle\,\mu(p,\,\alpha)\,|\psi_\alpha\rangle\langle\psi_\alpha|$$

This observable, interestingly, has the same eigenvectors as $p$ (being a superposition of projectors $|\psi_\alpha\rangle\langle\psi_\alpha|$ onto the eigenstates $\psi_\alpha$ of $p$), but with eigenvalues, *i.e.* measurements $\langle\psi_\alpha |x|\psi_\alpha\rangle\,\mu(p,\,\alpha)$ instead of $\mu(p,\,\alpha)$ (as is the case with the operator $p$). Naturally in the above $\alpha$ is an index variable ranging over the set of appropriate cardinality and integrals can replace the sums where appropriate.

Now, if we did measurement $x$ first, then $p$, the "observable" that would work out the appropriate mean value of the product of the measurements would be:

$$X_p=\sum\limits_\alpha \langle\tilde{\psi}_\alpha |p|\tilde{\psi}_\alpha\rangle\,\mu(x,\,\alpha)\,|\tilde{\psi}_\alpha\rangle\langle\tilde{\psi}_\alpha|$$

an operator with the same eigenvectors as $x$  (being a superposition of projectors $|\tilde{\psi}_\alpha\rangle\langle\tilde{\psi}_\alpha|$ onto the eigenstates $\tilde{\psi}_\alpha$ of $x$), but with eigenvalues, *i.e.* measurements $\langle\tilde{\psi}_\alpha |p|\tilde{\psi}_\alpha\rangle\,\mu(x,\,\alpha)$ instead of $\mu(x,\,\alpha)$. So in this case the mean of the product will be different from when we impart the measurements in the opposite order.

In your case, the application of these formulas is going to be tricky and needs to be handled with the appropriate theory of tempered distributions, since $x$ and $p$ do not have $\mathbf{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ eigenfunctions. Unfortunately, this is not a calculation I have ever done, so I can't write up a full solution yet.

Comment: I find this answer way too complicated. This is not a measurement theory question. This is a basic mathematical question. There is no need to argue using measurements.

Comment: @Nikodem If you read the original question carefully and [@Phoenix87's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/155105/26076) answer, you will see that this is not about how to do a standard mathematics problem - the original questioner gets the right answer. As someone with an interest in teaching, i tend to focus on what someone's misconceptions are, rather than on some arbitrary judgment on how a question "should" be answered. In this case, the question is about WHY the right answer seems wrong. I.e. imaginary valued. The essence is that the product is not self adjoint and cannot be a ....

Comment: @Nikodem ... operator that can be interpreted as an observable, i.e. yielding a measurement. It is then instructive to see what a meaningful, corresponding self adjoint operator would be, and the only way to do this is to think fundamentally what observables and measurements are about. A straight assertion that the OP has the right answer would leave them mystified. They would instantly ask WHY it is the wrong answer, in the light of Phoenix87 and [@Sofia's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/155094/26076) concise responses. Good, alternative answers on Phys SE often complement one another.

Comment: @Nikodem Indeed, the OP's acceptance of this answer would seem to show that it DID clear up this mystery for them.

Comment: It is a matter of taste whether one prefers a short answer to the point or a long one with a lecture. The questioner decides alone which answer he/she accepts. But other people can read SE to also learn from other answers (and vote for/against them). This is why SE is so great!

Answer (score 4):

Since you want the expectation value on a state with definite energy, say $|n\rangle$, then only $aa^\dagger$ and $a^\dagger a$ will give you some meaningful contributions (of course you can discard $a^\dagger a$ if $n=0$). So since it is an excited state you're interested in I will assume that $n\geq0$. Your expectation value is then
$$\langle n|xp|n\rangle=i\frac\hbar2\langle n|(aa^\dagger - a^\dagger a)|n\rangle.$$
Now recall that $[a,a^\dagger]=1$, whence
$$\langle n|xp|n\rangle=i\frac\hbar2\langle n|1|n\rangle = i\frac\hbar2.$$
There is nothing wrong with this, since, as someone pointed out $xp$ is not a self-adjoint operator in QM. So $\langle n|\ \cdot\ |n\rangle$, which defines a state on the C*-algebra of the observables is just a positive linear functional from operators to $\mathbb C$, which restricts to $\mathbb R$ on the self-adjoint elements.

Answer (score 3):

Is it really a mistake? Let me see using QM.

For calculating

$-i \hbar \int dx \ x \ \psi^* \frac {∂ \psi}{∂x},$

we can integrate by parts, use the fact that the solutions vanish at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, and obtain

$i \hbar \int dx \frac {∂ (x\ \psi ^*)}{∂x}\psi$

= $i \hbar \int dx \ \psi ^* \psi$ + $i \hbar \int dx \ x \frac {∂\psi ^*}{∂x}\psi .$

So, look what I get:

$-i \hbar \int dx \ x \ Re[\psi^* \frac {∂ \psi}{∂x}] = \frac {1}{2} i \hbar \int dx \ \psi ^* \psi = \frac {i \hbar }{2} .$

But, aren't the oscillator eigenfunctions real?

Comment: I don't quite follow why the real part is imaginary

Comment: @DepeHb: The real part isn't imaginary - look closely, the $\mathrm{i}$ was there in front of it the whole time.

Comment: Why use integrals to do this?